# How to list multiple variables into a single variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, list, variables

This is probably a really basic question, but either there is no answer on the web or I'm not using the correct terminology. I want to store two separate variables (A and B) into 1 master variable, so that master = A then B.

So if A = 3, B = 8, master would equal 38. Anyone know how to do this in JavaScript? I'm not a programmer but here is my attempt.

```
var A = 1;
var B = 5;

var master = A, B;

document.write(master);
```

Comment: `var master = {A:A, B:B};` or `var master = [A, B]`, depending on how you want to access each. The first, `master.A` and `master.B`, the second, `master[0]` and `master[1]`.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be requesting string concatenation. If you want an array, use one of the other answers. Otherwise: `var master = A.toString() + B.toString();` See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/METFe/).

Comment: The OPs terminology is not quite exact, but I think you get what they're after.

Answer (score 1):

Use an [`array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):

```
var A = 1,
    B = 5;

var master = [A, B];

master[0]; // 1
master[1]; // 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the array code, this will probably work better than what I'd hoped for.

Answer (score 0):

Both objects and arrays are OK, as has been suggested. I'll just throw in another suggestion - an encapsulation ;)

```
function Master(a, b) {
    this.first = a;
    this.second = b;

    this.both = function() {
        return a + '' + b;
    }
}
```

And to use it

```
var a = 3;
var b = 8;

var m = new Master(a, b);

alert(m.first);  // 3
alert(m.second); // 8
alert(m.both()); // 38 (mind the parentheses, this is a function call!)
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'm not sure I quite understand it yet, but will definitely give it a go and see if it works out better than the other two suggestions:)

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you're new, so I probably shouldn't being throwing arrays on you. However, for the others...

If you plan to get more dynamic than a few variables, you might want to invest in arrays.Put them into an array, then loop through the array printing them out as a string into a variable.

```
var myArray = new Array();

myArray.push(3);
myArray.push(8);

var myString = "";
for(var a = 0; a < myArray.length; a++)
{
    myString += myArray[a].toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, hadn't thought of running them through an array, that may work even better than my original idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
let 1st_new = [ [ 123, 'jack', 'white', 'tehran' ];
let 2nd_new= [ 456, 'roz', 'black', 'theran' ] ];

let 1st_list.push("1");
let 2st_list.push("2");

console.log(1st_new);
console.log(2nd_new);
```

#or you could make vairables of thge lists and put it inside a "var master" and     print that out.